# Implementing default , inbuild and custom repositories together

Tags: hibernate, oop, inheritance, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

This is the Set I have

**Interface to get default method**

```
interface Repo<T, ID extends Integer> extends JPARepository{ }
```

**Interface to add custom queries with inbuild syntax**

```
interface ExtendedRepo<T,ID extends Integer>{
 @Query("SELECT e.data from #{#entityName} e")
    public List getAll();
}
```

**Interface for Custom implementation**

```
interface CustomRepo<T, ID extends Integer>{
   public List search();
}

class CustomRepoImpl<T , ID extends Integer>{
  public List search() {  }
}
```

Now ,lets us assume an Entity called `Product`

How do I define `ProductRepository`. How do I implement all these interfaces

I tried to do this

```
@Repository
interface ProductRepository extends Repo<Product,Integer>,ExtendedRepo<Product, Integer> , CustomRepo<Product,Integer>{}
```

But when I try to deploy, am getting an error " No property `search` is found "

As you can see, the `search`  is from the `CustomRepo`

Comment: This is "Spring Data JPA API" not "JPA API". Tags fixed

Comment: OK.Thanks. Answer?

Comment: The most brilliant person who voted to close this question. request you you to give your reason here!